# Real and imaginary part from trigonometric form

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

In school I am learning for complex numbers in trigonometric form. 
$$z= a + bi r ( \cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha) )$$
In a problem I have to find the real and imaginary part from trigonometric form of
$$1 + \cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha)$$
For which I think the solution is

- Real part = $1+ \arccos(\alpha)$
- Imaginary part = $\arcsin(\alpha)$

PR2: $\sin(\alpha)+i\cos(\alpha)$
Update> 
For which I think the solution is>

- Real part = $\arcsin(\alpha)$
- Imaginary part = $\arccos(\alpha)$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note if you have a trigonometric form $$z = r(\cos a + i \sin a) = r\cos a + i r\sin a,$$ the imaginary part is $r\sin a$ and the real part is $r \cos a$.

E.g. if $z = 1 + i\sin(\pi/7) + \cos(\pi/13)$ then the imaginary part is the piece which is the multiple of $i$, so it is $\sin(\pi/7)$ and everything else is the real part, which here is $1 + \cos(\pi/13)$.

Another one to make it clear. Let
$$
z = 2 + 3i + \cos(\pi/5)i + \pi
  = (2+\pi) + i \left[3 + \cos(\pi/5) \right],
$$
So the real part is $2+\pi$ and the imaginary part is $3 + \cos(\pi/5)$.

Comment: And for the second one we have real = arcsin(α) imaginary = arccos(α) ?

Comment: @Triak i am not doing your homework for you. You do it and post an update if you need further hints, asking *very specifically* what it is you do not understand

Comment: Just check and tell me yes or no, thanks :)

Comment: @Triak no problem, but what to check -- i don't see any answers? what is the question you are doing and what is the answer you are proposing?

Comment: Updated in answer.

Comment: @Triak why $\arccos$ and $\arcsin$? Compare your problem with the first equation in my answer...